# Azure Active Directory and Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We're planning on migrating our TFS on premise to Azure DevOps. I understand that to migrate, we need Azure AD. My question is, what would be the subscription level should I get?

I'm fairly new to this so please go easy on me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Azure Subscription?

DevOps doesn't requires Azure Subscription. But if you anticipate needing to purchase any additional user plans, build/deployment pipelines, hosted build services, hosted load test services, or other developer services, we highly recommend making sure that you have an Azure Subscription ready for linking to your imported Azure DevOps Services organization once the import has completed.

You could refer to the migration guide first, which can be downloaded from website below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/

Comment: I apologize @Cece. My question is not clear. We already have an Azure Subscription. I'm asking about the subscription level for Azure AD. Currently, we are on free subscription only.